# How to fit spline through points in $ \mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: fitting, interpolation, splines

I have coordinates of points that represent a curve (for example, helix or centerline of moebius strip) in $ \mathbb{R^3}$. I want to fit a Bspline through these points. How to do this in Mathematica?

Example of curve: see at the end

I get noisy values for curvature and torsion of this curve if I use the pts as control points of `BSplineCurve` function.

Also, I have used `Interpolation` function, with that too, computed curvature and torsion are noisy. 
The real data I want to fit:

```
{{-0.127862, 7.23797, 0.080385}, {-0.386039, 7.22523, 
  0.238487}, {-0.643736, 7.19972, 0.395825}, {-0.900618, 7.16136, 
  0.551879}, {-1.15633, 7.11002, 0.706108}, {-1.4105, 7.04555, 
  0.857945}, {-1.66271, 6.96778, 1.00679}, {-1.9125, 6.8765, 
  1.15199}, {-2.15936, 6.77151, 1.29287}, {-2.40271, 6.6526, 
  1.42869}, {-2.64192, 6.51958, 1.55865}, {-2.87627, 6.37229, 
  1.68191}, {-3.10494, 6.21063, 1.79756}, {-3.32704, 6.03455, 
  1.90464}, {-3.54155, 5.84411, 2.00217}, {-3.74738, 5.63948, 
  2.08911}, {-3.9433, 5.42099, 2.1644}, {-4.12798, 5.18913, 
  2.227}, {-4.30001, 4.94459, 2.27587}, {-4.45787, 4.68829, 
  2.31007}, {-4.59997, 4.42139, 2.3287}, {-4.72468, 4.14532, 
  2.33102}, {-4.83036, 3.8618, 2.31646}, {-4.91539, 3.57279, 
  2.28468}, {-4.9782, 3.28055, 2.23561}, {-5.01738, 2.98756, 
  2.16947}, {-5.03167, 2.69648, 2.08687}, {-5.02007, 2.41015, 
  1.98876}, {-4.98187, 2.13143, 1.87651}, {-4.9167, 1.86318, 
  1.75186}, {-4.82458, 1.60813, 1.61691}, {-4.70594, 1.36881, 
  1.47412}, {-4.56163, 1.14739, 1.32615}, {-4.39291, 0.945657, 
  1.17587}, {-4.2014, 0.764887, 1.02622}, {-3.98905, 0.605816, 
  0.880086}, {-3.75804, 0.4686, 0.740214}, {-3.51073, 0.352823, 
  0.609092}, {-3.24952, 0.257522, 0.488851}, {-2.97682, 0.181251, 
  0.381183}, {-2.6949, 0.122163, 0.287282}, {-2.40588, 0.0781093, 
  0.207801}, {-2.11161, 0.0467557, 0.142845}, {-1.81367, 0.0256998, 
  0.0919741}, {-1.51331, 0.0125879, 0.0542331}, {-1.21151, 0.00522497,
   0.0282002}, {-0.908944, 0.00167311, 0.0120463}, {-0.60604, 
  0.00033535, 0.00360597}, {-0.303029, 0.0000222426, 0.000456223}, {0,
   0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0.303029, 0.000022046, -0.000449164}, {0.606041,
   0.000333794, -0.00357979}, {0.908945, 
  0.00166793, -0.0119886}, {1.21151, 0.00521293, -0.028099}, {1.51332,
   0.012565, -0.0540773}, {1.81368, 0.0256614, -0.0917535}, {2.11165, 
  0.0466967, -0.142551}, {2.40594, 0.0780248, -0.207425}, {2.69499, 
  0.122048, -0.286817}, {2.97694, 0.181102, -0.380626}, {3.24969, 
  0.257335, -0.488198}, {3.51095, 0.352596, -0.608342}, {3.75834, 
  0.468332, -0.739366}, {3.98943, 0.605506, -0.879142}, {4.20188, 
  0.764539, -1.02518}, {4.39349, 0.945273, -1.17475}, {4.56232, 
  1.14698, -1.32494}, {4.70675, 1.36837, -1.47283}, {4.82551, 
  1.60768, -1.61555}, {4.91775, 1.86271, -1.75043}, {4.98305, 
  2.13096, -1.87502}, {5.02137, 2.40969, -1.98722}, {5.0331, 
  2.69604, -2.08527}, {5.01892, 2.98713, -2.16782}, {4.97985, 
  3.28015, -2.23391}, {4.91715, 3.57242, -2.28293}, {4.83222, 
  3.86146, -2.31467}, {4.72663, 4.14502, -2.32918}, {4.602, 
  4.42112, -2.32682}, {4.45998, 4.68806, -2.30815}, {4.30219, 
  4.9444, -2.27392}, {4.13022, 5.18897, -2.225}, {3.94559, 
  5.42087, -2.16236}, {3.74972, 5.63939, -2.08703}, {3.54394, 
  5.84404, -2.00006}, {3.32946, 6.03451, -1.90249}, {3.1074, 
  6.21061, -1.79537}, {2.87875, 6.37229, -1.67969}, {2.64443, 
  6.51959, -1.5564}, {2.40524, 6.65262, -1.42641}, {2.1619, 
  6.77154, -1.29057}, {1.91506, 6.87653, -1.14966}, {1.66529, 
  6.96781, -1.00444}, {1.41309, 7.04558, -0.855578}, {1.15893, 
  7.11005, -0.703726}, {0.903221, 7.16138, -0.549484}, {0.646343, 
  7.19974, -0.393421}, {0.38865, 7.22524, -0.236076}, {0.130474, 
  7.23797, -0.077971}, {-0.127862, 7.23797, 0.080385}}
```

Comment: `Graphics3D[ BSplineCurve[pts] ]` only gives a Graphics3D object. How did you calculate curvature and torsion?

Comment: These are standard formulae for curvature and torsion compuation (ref: A Persseley- "Elementary Differential Geometry"), where t is any parameter. In the code below `Ifn` is the interpolated function. 

Curvature:

`curvK = (Dot[Cross[Ifn''[t], Ifn'[t]] , 
      Cross[Ifn'[t], 
       Ifn'[t]]]/ (Dot[Ifn'[t], Ifn'[t]])^3 )^(1/2) `

Torsion of curve: 

`torsionT =                            
  Dot[ Cross[Ifn'[t] , Ifn''[t]], Ifn'''[t]] / 
   Dot[ Cross[Ifn'[t], Ifn''[t]] , 
    Cross[Ifn'[t], Ifn'[t]] ]`

Comment: What is the definition of `Ifn[t]`?

Answer (score 6):

`BezierCurve` is only a Graphics3D-object. Use `BezierFunction` to describe a function.

Examplary here I give the calculation of the curvature `kappa` of the BezierFunction

```
pts = Table[{2 Cos[t], 2 Sin[t], 3*t}, {t, 0, 6, 0.01}];
x = BezierFunction[pts]

kappa = Sqrt[#.#] &[ D[x'[u]/Sqrt[x'[u].x'[u]], u]/Sqrt[x'[u].x'[u]]];
Plot[kappa, {u, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

[image]

which shows a smooth curvature function.

**answer to the modified question**

Let's call the data you gave `p`, then removing duplicate points

```
p=p// DeleteDuplicates;
```

Calculate arclength

```
si = Accumulate[Join[{{0}}, Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, Rest[pi] - Most[pi]]] ] // Flatten
```

Interpolate the points with piecewise splines

```
ip = Interpolation[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {si, pi}], Method -> "Spline"]
ParametricPlot3D[ip[s], {s, 0, Max[si]}]
```

[image]

The curvature can be calculated as in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it is still taking pts as control points, not fitting a curve through pts. Though the curvature and torsion are smooth now, the curve I get after selecting with `BezierCurve` far away from the pts.

Comment: I have edited the question and have included the real data points to fit.

Comment: Ok , what is the `curve parameter` of your new curve?

Comment: It is arc legth which I intend to compute later. But you may use any  equally spaced parameter, including the one in range [0,1].

Comment: Also, I found this demonstration closely related to what I need.  But I do not know, how to use it. https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GlobalBSplineCurveFittingByLeastSquares/

Comment: This demonstation approximates the points, you asked for interpolation !

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. My problem needs fit instead of interpolate (i.e approximate instead of exact). Because the curvature and torsion will be less nosiy.  I am able to reprdouce 2-d example with above demonstration (https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GlobalBSplineCurveFittingByLeastSquares/).  But I could not extend it to 3d points.

Comment: Ulrich correct me if I am asking a wrong question. All I need is a curve such that:  (i) It should be near to my data  (ii)  should have smooth curvature and torsion (these two become even more noisy when I increase the number of points. I am getting these points from a mechanics problem) and  (iii) should be a spline, because of continuity requirements.

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate noise in the data, it is best to perform a smoothing and not an interpolation. With the procedure that follows, three splines are adjusted one for each dimension, being that the degree of adjustment and smoothing is associated with the number of intermediate nodes. We will choose a grade 3 spline to make the adjustments. Given the data set **raw** we proceed as follows:

```
si = Accumulate[Join[{{0}}, Map[Sqrt[#.#] &, Rest[raw] - Most[raw]]]] // Flatten
X = Table[{si[[k]], raw[[k, 1]]}, {k, 1, Length[si]}];
Y = Table[{si[[k]], raw[[k, 2]]}, {k, 1, Length[si]}];
Z = Table[{si[[k]], raw[[k, 3]]}, {k, 1, Length[si]}];

SplineModel[data_, deg_, knots_] := Block[{basis, allKnots},
  basis = Array[\[FormalX]^# &, deg + 1, 0]~Join~Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, i, \[FormalX]], {i, 0, Length[knots] - deg - 2}];
  LinearModelFit[data, basis, \[FormalX]]];

knots = Range[0, 30, 3];
modX = SplineModel[X, 3, knots];
modY = SplineModel[Y, 3, knots];
modZ = SplineModel[Z, 3, knots];
ParametricPlot3D[{modX[s], modY[s], modZ[s]}, {s, 0, 30}]
```

So in **knots = Range[0, 30, 3];** we choose the number of knots. The present values are choose as an adequate minimum.

Answer (score 1):

```
searchSpan[knots_, u0_] :=
 With[{max = Max[knots]},
  If[u0 == max,
   Position[knots, max][[1, 1]] - 2,
   Ordering[UnitStep[u0 - knots], 1][[1]] - 2]
  ]

calcFitKnots[{m_, n_}, deg_, paras_] :=

 With[{d = (m + 1)/(n - deg + 1)},
  Join[ConstantArray[0, deg + 1],
   (*calculate the interior knots*)
   Function[{j},
     Module[{i, alpha}, i = Floor[j*d];
      alpha = j*d - i;
      (1 - alpha) paras[[i]] + alpha paras[[i + 1]]]
     ] /@ Range[1, n - deg],
   ConstantArray[1, deg + 1]]
  ]

calcParas[pts_, type_] :=
 Which[
  type === Automatic || type === "ChordLength",
  FoldList[
    Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts]), Total]] // N, 
  type === "Centripetal",
  FoldList[
    Plus, 0, Normalize[(Norm /@ Differences[pts])^(1/2), Total]] // N,
   type === "EqualSpaced",
  Range[0, 1, 1/(Length@pts - 1)] // N
  ]

(* Spline Fit *)
(* Data from simulations *)

pts = data3;
m = Length@pts - 1;
ControlPointsNumber = IntegerPart[Length[pts]/2];
splineDegree = 5;
Parametrization = "ChordLength";
(*achieve the value of options*)
cpn = ControlPointsNumber
pz = Parametrization
sd = splineDegree



paras = calcParas[pts, pz];
(*calculate the knots*)

knots = calcFitKnots[{m, cpn - 1}, sd, paras];
(*calculate the coefficients of matrix*)
coeffMat =
  (Function[{u0},
      With[{i = searchSpan[knots, u0]},
       Join[ConstantArray[0, i - sd],
        BSplineBasis[{sd, knots}, #, u0] & /@ Range[i - sd, i],
        ConstantArray[0, cpn - 1 - i]]]] /@ ArrayPad[paras, -1])[[All,
    2 ;; -2]];

(*solve the control points of the B-Spline curve*)

R = Transpose[coeffMat].(pts[[2 ;; -2]] -
     With[{Q0 = First@pts, Qm = Last@pts},
      BSplineBasis[{sd, knots}, 0, #] Q0 +
         BSplineBasis[{sd, knots}, cpn - 1, #] Qm & /@ 
       ArrayPad[paras, -1]]);
ctrlpts =
  Join[{First@pts},
   LinearSolve[Transpose@coeffMat.coeffMat, R], {Last@pts}];
(*visualize the fitting result*)
p1 = Graphics3D[
   BSplineCurve[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> sd, SplineKnots -> knots]
   ];
p2 = ListPointPlot3D[pts];
Show[p1, p2]


Ifn3 = BSplineFunction[ctrlpts, SplineDegree -> sd, 
  SplineKnots -> knots, SplineClosed -> True]
curvK3I = (Dot[Cross[Ifn3''[t], Ifn3'[t]] , 
      Cross[Ifn3''[t], Ifn3'[t]]]/ (Dot[Ifn3'[t], Ifn3'[t]])^3 )^(1/2);
torsion3I = 
  Dot[ Cross[Ifn3'[t] , Ifn3''[t]], Ifn3'''[t]] / 
   Dot[ Cross[Ifn3'[t], Ifn3''[t]] , Cross[Ifn3'[t], Ifn3''[t]] ];
plotK3I = 
 Plot[Evaluate[{curvK3, curvK3I}], {t, 0., 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0., 01}, {-0.1, 0.6}}]
plotT3I = Plot[torsion3I, {t, 0., 1}]
```